# reorder a column with phpMyAdmin using InnoDB storage engine does not work

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

Today I tried to reorder a column of a table using phpMyAdmin (as I have done many times before).
Although the result was displayed as successful no reordering effectively happened.

It appears the problem is caused by using InnoDB as storage engine which is the default value from MySQL 5.5 onward.
When I changed back to myIsam the problem was solved. It clarified why it was working on some tables.

Is this a solvable mySQL problem? Or is this regular expected behavior for InnoDB ?
In the latter case phpMyAdmin should perhaps be adapted to not offer the functionality while using InnoDB.

MySQL: 5.5.29
phpMyAdmin: 4.0.4

Comment: Try with some other GUI clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *...reordering column...* you meant

```
 ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY ...
```

then for InnoDB table that has a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE KEY` it doesn't work. It's by design:

> **[ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)**
>   ORDER BY **does not make sense for InnoDB** tables that contain a
>   user-defined clustered index (PRIMARY KEY or NOT NULL UNIQUE index).
>   InnoDB always orders table rows according to such an index if one is
>   present.

On the other hand if you don't have `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE KEY` in your table, which is highly unlikely, then MySQL will allow you to change the order.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbc28/1)** demo that demonstrates that behavior.

Comment: Yes, my title was actually inaccurate. In fact it reorders the table and I meant ALTER TABLE. So this is regular expected behavior and perhaps phpMyAdmin could be enhanced by not offering this functionality under the Operations tab.

Comment: @AFvS As I showed in a second example it can be used if you don't have a PK or UNIQUE KEY in your table. Although I agree it doesn't have much sense in a real world scenarios.